# Comparing 2 strings (Days of week) no effect

Tags: string, validation, compare, equals, dayofweek

I am trying to validate sVenueDay (text entered via textbox), to make sure the value entered is a valid day. I entered "Sunday" into txtBoxVenueDay.Text. When running the program, the "Input entered not valid day" is displayed even though "Sunday" entered is a valid day. I tried using !sVenueDay.Equals("Sunday") format (and for other days as well) but nothing :/

```
string sVenueDay = txtBoxVenueDay.Text;

if (sVenueDay != "Monday" || sVenueDay != "Tuesday" || sVenueDay != "Wednesday" || sVenueDay != "Thursday" || sVenueDay != "Friday" || sVenueDay != "Saturday" || sVenueDay != "Sunday")

    {
        lblOutput.Text = "Input entered not valid day";
        return;
    }

 else
    lblOutput.Text = "Valid day";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking whether it's not equal to "Monday" *or* it's not equal to "Tuesday". Can you propose which string is equal to both "Monday" *and* "Tuesday"? :)

I suspect you want:

```
if (sVenueDay != "Monday" && sVenueDay != "Tuesday" && ...)
```

Or, rather more usefully:

```
private static readonly HashSet<string> ValidDays = new HashSet<string>(
    new[] { "Monday", "Tuesday", ... });

...

if (!ValidDays.Contains(sVenueDay))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When your using or if first condition is true then i will not check the next conditions.. So first check true then false ; Try like following:(use equals method)
  string sVenueDay = txtBoxVenueDay.Text;if (sVenueDay == "Monday" || sVenueDay == "Tuesday" || sVenueDay == "Wednesday" || sVenueDay == "Thursday" || sVenueDay == "Friday" || sVenueDay == "Saturday" || sVenueDay == "Sunday")   {       lblOutput.Text = "valid day";       return;   }else   lblOutput.Text = "Input entered not Valid day";